# Error when building custom ros2 msg, cannot find .hpp file

Tags: ros2, colcon

I am getting this error when attempting to build my custom ros2 msg. I followed this tutorial on creating a custom ros2 msg (https://docs.ros.org/en/crystal/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html), but when i get to the final step of running:

```
colcon build --packages-select mbs_ros_msgs
```

I get the following error:

```
root@docker-desktop:/home/ros2_ws# colcon build --packages-select mbs_ros_msgs
Starting >>> mbs_ros_msgs
--- stderr: mbs_ros_msgs                             
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__functions.c:4:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__functions.c:4:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make:167: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__functions.c.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make:153: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__functions.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:213: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp:7:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp:7:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/build.make:122: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/build.make:136: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:395: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp:4:
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp:11:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp:12:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/build.make:144: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp:4:
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp:11:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp:12:
/home/ros2_ws/build/mbs_ros_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: 'mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp' file not found
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/build.make:130: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:369: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
1 error generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/build.make:144: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/mbsgpssync__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/build.make:130: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/mbsephtoa__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:291: CMakeFiles/mbs_ros_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< mbs_ros_msgs [2.07s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [2.16s]
  1 package failed: mbs_ros_msgs
  1 package had stderr output: mbs_ros_msgs
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt from my custom message package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(mbs_ros_msgs)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/MBSEPHTOA.msg"
  "msg/MBSGPSSYNC.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs 
 )

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()
```

And this is my package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>mbs_ros_msgs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="gilbertogonzalez@todo.todo">gilbertogonzalez</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

I can't imagine that the issue is in any of the above files. I am not sure why I am seeing this error. Please let me know if you need further information, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly late response, but check the naming conventions for the .hpp files included. You seem to have the following based on the error:

```
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
```

Based on the .msg names in the CMakeLists you should have

```
#include "mbs_ros_msgs/msg/m_b_s_e_p_h_t_o_a.hpp"
```

and a similar format for the other message type.